# Event Reciever on specific list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, custom-list, event-receivers

I am working on creating event reciever for a custom list in sharepoint 2010 using visual studio..how can this event reciever be targeted to a specific custom list ..in my case its customEmpList?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to declaratively attach the event receiver, you may specify ListUrl in the Receivers Element.

```
<Receivers
  ListTemplateId = "Text"
  ListTemplateOwner = "Text"
  ListUrl = string
  RootWebOnly = TRUE | FALSE
  Scope = Site | Web>
</Receivers>
```

[How to: Create an Event Receiver for a Specific List Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Create a feature that upon activation have the proper code to attach to a specific list for e.g. :

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)   
    {   
       SPWeb site = null;   
       try  
       {   
              //Adds the overridden ItemUpdated Event Receiver to a list   
               site = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;   
               SPList lst = site.Lists["customEmpList"];   
               string asmName = "AssemblyNameOfYourEventHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=EnterThePublicKeyTokenHere";   
               string itemReceiverName = "Namespace.ClassOfEventHandler";   
               lst.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdated, asmName, itemReceiverName);   
               lst.Update() 
        } 
     catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }


     finally
     {

       site.Dispose();

     }
```

}

The following link contains other possible ways of attaching event handlers : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/18/event-handlers-part-3-register-event-handlers-plus-free-site-settings-manage-event-handlers-add-on.aspx